# Extjs5 with Symfony2 Folder structure

Tags: symfony, extjs, extjs5

I am using Extjs 5 with symfony2. I created Extjs 5 project under /web/MyApp_app

MyPrject Struct like this

```
Symfony2Project
   web
   app.php
   app_dev.php
   MYApp_app     //this is Extjs 5 project
      index.html
```

Please let me know how to access extjs page with symfony router.

i dont want to directly access index.html by MyApp.dev/web/MYApp_app/index.html.(i can able to view extjs page by this way. But i want to use symfony router to access this page after user successfully login)

I want to access like the following url
http://myapp.dev/web/app_dev.php/myapp-app
Here i receive http://myapp.dev/web/app_dev.php/myapp-app/ext/packages/sencha-core/.sencha/package/Boot.js?_dc=1406021528655 error

So i changed few lines in bootstrap.js like below

```
//bootstrap.js   #420
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    Boot.loadUrl("../MyApp_app/"+urls[i], request);
}
```

But this not working in production build. Please let me know how to access extjs page with symfony router.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to edit any `bootstrap.*` file directly - they get re-generated continuously.

If you need to edit the bootstrap, inside the `.sencha/app` directory you will find a number of property files and templates. `Boot.js` is used as the template for the bootstrap; you can apply changes there.

However, from the looks of this, you're probably better off editing your `app.json` file, and changing the `classpath` property; this is the property that determines where your source code lives.